# How to change ftp path?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ftp

I have apache installed on my ubuntu machine. you can access the server from other machines with `http://linux-server` The local path on the machine is `/var/www` I have installed vsftpd on the machine as well so I can ftp to the server from another machine with `ftp://linux-server` however it takes me to `/home/myUserName` I want the ftp to take me to the same place as the http. So how can I change the FTP path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you login as a user, vsftp will default to putting you in that user's home directory.  If you want to ftp to linux-server and have it drop you into `/var/www`, the easiest way would be to create an FTP user who's home directory is set to `/var/www`.

Alternately, a better solution might be to setup anonymous FTP, and make the anonymous FTP directory be `/var/www/` (assuming you don't need it to be restricted and secured (of course, if you do, you should be using ssh/scp/sftp)).

Comment: thanks, can you go into further detail about how to add a new user and set its home directory to /var/www. Thanks!!

Comment: 'useradd' is the command you want.  `useradd -d /var/www newuser` will create an account named 'newuser', with the correct home directory.  Then use `passwd newuser` to change the account name.

This all assumes you have root on the box.

Answer (score 1):

the anonymous FTP directory is `/var/ftp/`.  If you want to change it to another directory, do:

`sudo vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

or in some cases:
`sudo vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

and edit this variable:
`anon_root=/NewDirectoryPath/ftp/`